# Rails/Ruby logging, how to "buffer/dump" logging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I'm wondering if there is some way of "buffering" Rails.logger (ruby Logger) output.

```rb
Rails.logger.buffer # start buffering content, pending decision later to log or discard it

if check1
  Rails.logger.info "Valid date: check1"
else
  Rails.logger.info "Invalid data: check1"
end

# ...

if check15
  Rails.logger.info "Valid date: check15"
else
  Rails.logger.info "Invalid data: check15"
end

if does_exist_in_database
  Rails.logger.buffer.clear  # I am no longer interested in the logs cached up till now
else
  Rails.logger.buffer.output # I am interested in the logs cached; "log" it!
  Rails.logger.error "Error in data ..."
end
```

I could come up with a class that would easily do this.  I wanted to know if anyone else has come across this and has an elegant solution?

In terms of the final outcome, there are tons of logs that I end up having to review (visually) that just take up space and if the data is ok, the logs are useless.  Thus removing them from the log (output/file) will save space and time all around!

-daniel

Comment: There are tons of tutorials and blog posts as well as [a section in the guides dedicated to Rails loggers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger). Recommendations for such resources are off topic as is "code fishing".  https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+writing+a+custom+logger

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?q=rails+logging